# Bleeding over edges of Samsung TV, cant see menu bar

Tags: hdmi

For some reason my Raspberry Pi 3b is bleeding off the edges of the screen, and I am unable to see my menu bar. This happened after a reboot, and wasn't happening before.

I am using HDMI as my input/output.
Samsung smart TV

I turned off overscanning, as well as tried a few other fixes, found online, to no avail.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have some zoom mode enabled on the TV. Because I had similar problem with half of subtitle missing when watching movie.

Answer (score 2):

`hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` may help you in the [`config.txt` settings](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md). There are a lot of different resolutions and refresh rates. If you are using Kodi or derivative, there's a helpful calibration tool in the [display settings](http://kodi.wiki/view/Settings/System/Display).